# UI.selectmenu from jQuery is not imported!

Tags: 7, javascript

I have this function to add libraries from jQuery UI, but the *selectmen*, and *tooltip* seems to be missing! anyone know how to import them in Drupal 7.4?

```
function kalender_init() {
    $lib= array(
        'drupal.ajax', 'drupal.form', 
        'drupal.autocomplete',
        'jquery', 'ui','ui.selectable',
        'ui.droppable','ui.draggable',
        'ui.sortable','ui.resizable',
        'ui.tabs','ui.dialog',
        'ui.datepicker','ui.autocomplete',
        'ui.button', 'ui.buttonset',
        'ui.selectmenu', 'ui.tooltip',
        'form'
    );
    foreach($lib as $l){
        drupal_add_library('system', $l);
    }
}
```

I need for the form over here:

```
foreach($result as $color){
    array_push($colors, $color->name);
}
foreach($colors as $color => $id){
    array_push($attr, array('class' => array('colors-list'), 'data-color' => $color) );
}
$form['gruppen']['checkbox'][$group->id]['color'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#suffix' => '<div class="clear-both"></div></div>',
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#options' => $colors,
    '#options_attributes' => $attr,
);
```

Comment: You can check the list of core jQuery UI library from `system_library()` in system.module

Comment: Where? how? I see in the folder misc/ui/ that there is no tooltip and no selectmenu, you are able to display structured information about librarys?? @JimmyKo

Comment: @JimmyKo just to look inside the system.module? or to debug with the system_librark()?

Comment: You don't need to debug with `system_library()`. I just provide you the location where the core library register to support the using of `drupal_add_library()`

Answer (score 0):

[Selectmenu Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) is added in jQuery UI 1.11, which is not supported by core and also jquery_update module. There is an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2197249) on Drupal.org.

[Tabs Widget](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) is added since jQuery UI 1.9, you can have it if you installed latest version of jquery_update module with proper configuration.

Comment: So i am force to use $form['#attached']['js']? Found it here: https://www.drupal.org/node/304255

Comment: You can try to add the latest jQuery UI with $form['#attached']['js'], but I don't know if it can work perfectly in Drupal anyway.